# Salesforce Apex - When feedItem of Type 'EmailMessageEvent' is created through apex code, its not visible on the record level page

Tags: salesforce, apex

when a FeedItem of Type 'EmailMessageEvent' is created using apex code its getting created in the backend but not showing in the record Page

This is my observation

//The record will not be visible in chatter but its created in the Database

```
`FeedItem feed1 = new FeedItem();
feed1.Type = 'EmailMessageEvent';
feed1.ParentId = '5007j00000GSDb8AAH';
feed1.Body = 'Hi this an email from code';
feed1.Title = 'Email from Code';
feed1.Visibility = 'InternalUsers';
insert feed1;`
```

[feeditem record in the in DataExport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuwQf.png)

//

but

//This creates a chatter and its visible in the recordpage

```
`Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
 String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'l.......@gmail.com'};
 email.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
 email.setSubject('Test Email from Salesforce');
 email.setPlainTextBody('This is a test email sent from Salesforce Apex.');
 email.setWhatId('5007j00000GSDb8AAH');//Case record Id
Messaging.SendEmailResult[] sendResults = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{email});

        // Check the results of the send operation
        for (Messaging.SendEmailResult result : sendResults) {
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                System.debug('Email sent successfully.');
            } else {
                System.debug('Failed to send email: ' + result.getErrors()[0].getMessage());
            }
        }`
```

[Record Page chatter feed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nM8dF.png)

Why can't the feedItem of Type EmailMessageEvent be visible on the record page